# How do I send a UDP datagram with source address 0.0.0.0 in Rust?

Tags: sockets, networking, rust, udp, dhcp

I am writing a DHCP client in Rust.

The client must send a DHCPDISCOVER message when there are no configured interfaces. Tools like `dhclient` are able to do that by sending the message with source address `0.0.0.0`.

Unfortunately, with high level Rust primitives I cannot tweak IP header.

Should I completely move to a low level networking solution (libc, nix) or is there a better approach?

The binding code:

```
let socket = UdpBuilder::new_v4()?;
let socket = socket.bind(addr)?;
let socket = UdpSocket::from_std(socket, &Handle::default())?;
socket.set_broadcast(true)?;
```

`UdpBuilder` is from the `net2` crate.

`UdpSocket` is from the `tokio` crate.

`addr` = `SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(0,0,0,0)), 68)`

Comment: Not intimate w/ DHCP discovery protocol, but does net::UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:68") accomplish what you're looking to send?

Comment: No. My sockets are always bound like that. If there are no configured interfaces, bind returns no errors, but send-like methods return 'Network unreachable'. If there is a configured interface, the socket gets bound to it and the source address is the IP of the interface. If there were a way to use unbounded sockets (looks like unix stuff allows that, but I'm not sure yet), it could succeed.

Comment: how are you connecting? Perhaps a code snippet of what you're doing now would be helpful

Comment: Posted the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with Rust's high level UDP abstractions.

Low level packet builders must be used instead. For example, BPF on FreeBSD and Mac OS.